# Using fping to get ping times in Python

Tags: python, network-programming, ping, icmp

I have a list of IP's (Generated from a traceroute in Python Scapy) which I need to send 3 ping's to measure the average time to each hop. My first methord was building a ICMP request using sockets and measuring the time for response. But it is inaccurate and slow when pinging multiple hosts. I did try and use normal Linux ping, but my `for i` loop was being blocked while waiting for the response, obviously I want all the ping requests to be send out at the same time.

So I'm looking for a way to use `fping` in Linux which I give a list of IP's and then let that do the work of building packets. But I'm not sure how to pass a list of arguments to a shell command or get the data back into an array for further processing after it has completed.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: Remember that applications do not use ICMP, and ICMP is on the bottom of the list for treatment in congestion, so the ICMP times have no relation to application performance with TCP or UDP. Ping is really designed to test IP connectivity, not application or network performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about `fping`, but something like this...

```
import subprocess

CMD = ['fping', 'param1', 'param2']

result = subprocess.check_output(CMD)
```

...will run `fping param1 param2`, and put the output as a string into the `result` variable, once the `fping` process has terminated.

You can split the output into lines with `result.splitlines()`.

Here's quick one-liner example using `ping` to grab three ping times to localhost...

```
>>> [line.rpartition('=')[-1] for line in subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-c', '3', 'localhost']).splitlines()[1:-4]]
['0.028 ms', '0.023 ms', '0.025 ms']
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. I just need to pass the output and put the whole lot in an array. The lines I'm getting are like this: `127.0.0.1 is alive (1.0 ms)` how can I dump both the IP and the ping time in an array?

Comment: @dx282 If you're comfortable with regular expressions, take a look at the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module for parsing the output.

Answer (score 0):

The following function parses `fping`'s output and returns a dictionary containing the availability for every host:

```
import subprocess
from typing import List, Dict

def ping(hosts: List[str], timeout: int = 500) -> Dict[str, bool]:
    command = ["fping", "-t", str(timeout)] + hosts
    proc    = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    parse   = lambda stream: [
        line.split(" ")
        for line
        in stream.read().decode("UTF-8").split("\n")
        if len(line) != 0
    ]
    lines = parse(proc.stdout) + parse(proc.stderr)
    return {p[0]: p[-1] == "alive" for p in lines if p[1] == 'is'}

print(ping(["google.com", "asdfasdfasdf1234.com", "stackoverflow.com"]))
# {'google.com': True, 'stackoverflow.com': True, 'asdfasdfasdf1234.com:': False}
```